# Start WSO2 Enterprise Integrator as a service in windows not work

Tags: yajsw, wso2-esb

I followed the instructions in [Installing EI as Windows service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service), but I am unable to start the service.
Below the output of runConsole.bat of YAJSW (both with yajsw-stable-11.11 and with yajsw-stable-12.08)

```
C:\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat>runConsole.bat

C:\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat>pushd C:\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat\

C:\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat>call setenv.bat
"java" -Xmx30m -Djna_tmpdir="C:\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat\/../tmp" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar "C:\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat\/../wrapper.jar" -c "C:\yajsw-st
able-12.08\bat\/../conf/wrapper.conf"
YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
OS   : Windows 7/6.1/amd64
JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_121/C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121/64
mar 30, 2017 3:54:18 PM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFORMAZIONI: Using "C:\Users\Sexxa\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:18|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:18|OS   : Windows 7/6.1/amd64
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:18|JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_121/C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121/64
system.env 61
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:19|started process with pid 18140
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:19|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:19|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:19|stopping process with pid/timeout 18140 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:20|process exit code: 1
system.env 61
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:25|started process with pid 4508
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:25|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:25|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:25|stopping process with pid/timeout 4508 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:26|process exit code: 1
system.env 61
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:31|started process with pid 14232
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:31|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:31|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:31|stopping process with pid/timeout 14232 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:32|process exit code: 1
system.env 61
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:37|started process with pid 17972
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:37|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:37|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:37|stopping process with pid/timeout 17972 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:38|process exit code: 1
system.env 61
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:43|started process with pid 14460
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:43|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:43|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:43|stopping process with pid/timeout 14460 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:44|process exit code: 1
system.env 61
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:49|started process with pid 7148
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:49|too many restarts
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-30 15:54:49|Shutting down Wrapper
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with workaround: using YAJSW 11.03 and run YAJSW script with administrator rights

Comment: WSO2 recommends Yet Another Java Service Wrapper (YAJSW) 11.XX versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wrapper.conf that is located in your WSO2 EI folder. 
Path: ...\wso2-ei\bin\yajsw\wrapper.conf. And what version of WSO2 EI are you using?

Comment: I have already used the CARBON_HOME\bin\yajsw\wrapper.conf. EI version is 6.0.0